# Buffers around areas

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

For ArcGIS it wants us to make a map that intersects a buffer around networks that are 20ft from a building, but not within 200ft of an existing bike rack. It said create a buffer zone around the bike rack zone where it does not contain this data, but how do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Lea. Please review our tour to help get you started: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour. Also see the following document to help aid you in editing this question to meet the minimum guidelines of this site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Once edited, you can vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two separate buffers: one for 200ft within bike racks and another for 20ft from a buildings.

Then use the intersect tool to see exactly where the two buffers over lap each other.Simply remove that area and the areas you have left from 20ft of existing bike racks